# How to use permutation on an array of arbitrary size in TTCN-3?

Tags: arrays, permutation, ttcn

I have an array in TTCN-3 that I want to use the command **permutation** on. That is usually done like this:

```
myArray := { permutation( myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2] ) };
```

The result is that when I expect the result to be myArray, the order of the elements doesn't matter.

However, this requires hard-coding of the actual values in the array, like above, where I specifically tell permutation what values of the array I want present. I am now in a situation where I have an array that I from the code don't know the size of. I can find the size of my array with

```
sizeof(myArray);
```

so if I could use that value that I get in runtime to specify how the permutation should be done, that would be great. What I want to accomplish is something like this

```
myArray := { permutation( myArray[0], ... , myArray[n] ) };
```

where n is the size of the array, which I do not know from the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your special case maybe a "set of" would be the desired construct. A set of values matches a list of same values in any order.

Nevertheless there is a processed change request for the TTCN-3 language at ([CR6088](http://t-ort.etsi.org/view.php?id=6088)), extending the BNF to support also dynamic lists as parameters for superset, subset, permutation and complement.

The CR was accepted and will be published in the new TTCN-3 Edition 4.5.1 (for details please  Section B.1.3.3). The 4.5.1 TTCN-3 Core Language Standard should be available at http://www.ttcn-3.org/.

Please find below the example (from the standard document) that shows the usage as defined by Edition 4.5.1:

```
type record of integer RoI;
template RoI t_RoI1 := {1, 2, *};
template RoI t_RoI2 := {permutation(0, all from t_RoI1), 4, 5}; 
// results in {permutation(0, 1, 2, *), 4, 5}
```

Best regards,
Bogdan